# Global object of android app

Tags: java, android

i am developing an android app.
I have some activities in it. And i must have an object which can be available from all activities. 
Any ideas how to organize it?

Comment: what do you mean by "global object"? If you mean a class that is available all over the application, then look at this thread http://androidforums.com/developer-101/124278-global-objects.html

Comment: In my situation it must be an object of some class. In all activities I must to use this object's methods, add data into object's fields and so on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the global `Application` object in the following way:

```
package com.yourpackagename;

public class App extends Application {
}
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application android:name=".App">
```

To access it from an `Activity`:

```
App globalApp = (App) getApplicationContext();
```

The `App` class will be instantiated automatically when the app starts. It will be available as long as the application process is alive. It can act as a global store in which you can put your things and have access to them throughout the application lifetime.

Comment: I feel like there are some typos in this, but I don't know which ones to correct! :)

Comment: corrected typos. feel free to comment if I am missing anything.

Comment: Your initial class definition is `GolbalObject`, but your usage is `GlobalObject`..

Comment: Thanks.Corrected my spell mistake.

Comment: According to this post:   http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/  this is horribly wrong.

Comment: @Chris In the above answer 1) I had stated it can act as global store not with respect to data. 2) I had stated "It can" it does not mean you should do this way It's a suggestion not an order 3) There are libs for which we need to use application object for eg :: Dagger2 ,  Craslytics etc ..

Comment: Do you take issue with the article I linked to, or do you generally agree?

Comment: Yes chris I generally agree.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do this. If the object you want to share is a String (or easily described with a String), I would recommend [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). It serves as a key-value store for sharing data within an application.

If this is not the case (i.e. the suitability of a String), you could consider passing it as an extra with the Intent that launches your various activities. For example:

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(CurrentActivity.class, ActivityToLaunch.class);
newActivity.putExtra("object_key", Bundle_With_Your_Object);
```

For more details on this strategy (especially about the Bundle class, if you're not familiar), I would read [this Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29).

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences in this case:

**To add or edit:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("Cusom Name", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("your_key", value).commit();
```

**To clear:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("Cusom Name", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().clear();
```

**To get value:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("Cusom Name", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);               
String value = prefs.getString("your_key", "");
```

Comment: this assumes that the object that the poster wants to share is a String, which may or may not be a good assumption; although, perhaps the "best" solution is to have a toString and constructor such that Object x = new Object(y.toString());
will give an x that is equivalent to y?

Comment: I think he need some attributes of an object instead of a real object. Pass object over an intent is another good way but the code for sending and handling it is complex.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a class named MasterActivity which extends Activity and define your global object.

```
public class MasterActivity extends Activity
{
     public Object mObject;
}
```

Then, you have to extend your main activity class with your MasterActivity like it :

```
// your main activity
public class MainActivity extends MasterActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // you can now use mObject in your main class
        mObject.yourmethod();
    }
}
```

By this way, you will be able to use your object in all your activities simply by extending MasterActivity instead of Activity.